# Post JSON object to server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a little problem with posting my JavaScript object to the server (asp.net 4.5 c#).

the object is created by user (i´m using jquery for that), and then user shod be able to send that object to server to process the information,

the data i need to send to the server is array of jQuery objects,

I´ve already tried this but it didnt worked :

```
 var sendOrder = function () {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Products.aspx/ProcessOrder",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          data: JSON.stringify(addedProducts),
          success: function (result) {
            debugger;
            alert(result);
          },
          error: function (result) {
            debugger;
            alert(result.responseText);
          }
        });
      }

      sendOrderInfo.bind('click', sendOrder);
```

server side method is :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string ProcessOrder(object orderInfo) {
      return "Order Processed Successfully";
    }
```

and the object (array of objects) posted looks like this :

```
addedProducts
[
Object
product: "Cerejas"
quantity: "45"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
product: "Farinheira"
quantity: "4"
__proto__: Object
]
```

Does anyone have some idea?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not helpful. Please be more descriptive in describing how it doesn't work.

Comment: try changing your `data` to `{ orderInfo: JSON.stringify(addedProducts) }`

Comment: can you try to alert the json data your are sending, to check if its present, something like this :  'alert(JSON.stringify(addedProducts));'

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are following this process :

creating a class for the Objects

```
public class Products
{
    public string product { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public bool ProcessOrder(Products orderInfo)
{
    return orderInfo != null;
}
```

**json call :**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Products.aspx/ProcessOrder",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(addedProducts),
    success: function(response) {
        response ? alert("It worked!") : alert("It didn't work.");
    }
});
```

Do let me know if it works for you.